# For maximum value of $ P(t) \ $

Tags: maxima-minima

Find the maximum value of $ \ P(t) \ $ given by

$P(t)=0.0000000 219 t^4-0.0000 167 t^3+0.00155t^2+0.002t+0.23 \ $

For what value of $ \ t\ $ , $ \ P(t) \ $ is maximum ?

**Answer:**

For maximum value of $ P(t) \ $,

$ P(t)'=0 \\ \Rightarrow 4 \times 0.0000000219 \ t^3-3 \times 0.0000167 \ t^2+0.00155 \ t+0.002 =0 \ $

**But from this how to get the solution ?**

Is Newton-raphson method applicable here ?

**I need help .**

Comment: your derivative is with error, check it again then factorize using technique explained here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118291/how-to-factorize-this-cubic-equation; you will get two or more intervals, in each intervals find the sign of the slope/derivative and then find max

Answer (score 1):

$$P(t)'=0  \Rightarrow 4 \times 0.0000000219 \ t^3-3 \times 0.0000167 \ t^2+2\times 0.00155 \ t+0.002 =0 $$

$t_1= -0.638564; \; t_2 = 71.3329;\; t_3 = 501.223$

To understand which is maximum second derivative test is the best method

$P''(t)=0.0031 - 0.0001002 t + 2.628\times 10^{-7} t^2$

$P''(t_1)=0.00316409>0$ then $t_1$ is a minimum

$P''(t_2)=-0.00271033<0$ then $t_2$ is a maximum

$P''(t_3)=0.0188993>0$ then $t_3$ is another minimum

Hope this can be useful

*Edit*

How did I find the roots?

Well, I'll show $t_2$ which is the maximum

First I made a table of values to look for signs changing. Like this

$
\begin{array}{l|l}
  x & f'(x) \\
\hline
 10 & 0.0280776 \\
 20 & 0.0446608 \\
 30 & 0.0522752 \\
 40 & 0.0514464 \\
 50 & 0.0427 \\
 60 & 0.0265616 \\
 70 & 0.0035568 \\
 80 & -0.0257888 \\
 90 & -0.0609496 \\
 100 & -0.1014 \\
\end{array}
$

Therefore a root is in the interval $[70,80]$

I set $t_0=70$ and then, recursively

$$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{f'(t_n)}{f''(t_n)}$$

we get

$
\begin{array}{l|l}
 n & t_n\\
\hline
 0 & 70 \\
 1 & 71.3543 \\
 2 & 71.3329 \\
 3 & 71.3329 \\
\end{array}
$

so $t\approx 71.3329$

Comment: How did you get these roots? which method,

Comment: @mabmath Newton converges quite quickly

Comment: @mabmath I edited my answer to show the way I used to find a root. The tables can be done in a spreadsheet, for instance