# Convert very large number into a reducible polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials, factoring

I need to decompose a large integer (30-40 digits) to an integer unknown with a factorizable polynomial. As a small example:
$$
    \begin{cases}
      119=2x^2+3x \\
      x=7 \\
    \end{cases}
$$

For example:

$$54026707855643784^2+2 \cdot 54026707855643784$$

$$= 2918885161719081869258276809126224$$

This is easy to do for a specific form such as $x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y) $. For instance, if we wanted to find a polynomial of that form for the number $2960$, we could search $x$ such that $x^2-2960$ is a perfect square. We have a lower bound of $\text{ceil}(\sqrt{2960}) = 55$. We soon find that $57^{2}-2960 = 289$,  the perfect square of 17, so we get the expression:

$$
    \begin{cases}
      2960=x^2-289 \\
      x=57 \\
    \end{cases}
$$

However, there is not such an expression for all numbers, such as even very small numbers like $6$. Plus, for larger numbers it could take hundreds of trials till you hit a solution. Thus, I'm trying to find a more general effiicient algorithm for *any* reducible/factorizable polynomial (making it less likely for flanks like 6 to appear). However, I can find no methods that aren't computationally expensive (e.g. searching a lookup table would take a long time). So is there an algorithm for this?

Comment: This makes no sense.  Give an example with 30–40 digits and what you seek as a result.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Here is an example: 54026707855643784^2+2*54026707855643784 = 2918885161719081869258276809126224.

Comment: General lesson on posting questions and answering queries:  Put your example *IN THE PROBLEM* so anyone reading can easily see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try representing the integer $z$ in its base-$b$ form for different $b$.

For eg: In base-10,

$$z = 2960 = 2.10^3 + 9.10^2 + 6.10 + 0 = 2960_{10}$$

So,

$$(x, f(x) = (10, 2x^3 + 9x^2 + 6x)$$

In base-$7$, we have $2960 = 11426_7$. So,

$$(x, f(x)) = (7, x^4 + x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x + 6)$$

You can represent $2960$ in many bases $b \in [2,z-1]$ and get different $f(x)$. You can then check if the polynomial is reducible (or irreducible).

See: [Methods to see if a polynomial is irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/methods-to-see-if-a-polynomial-is-irreducible)

However, this is not any more efficient than factoring $z$. There are faster algorithms for factoring $z$ than this.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670070/242) for more on radix rep's, e.g. Cohn's irreducibility test, and related matters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are seeking so-called *algebraic factorizations* of integers, i.e. factorizations that arise by representing an integer by reducible polynomials. Your example using a difference of squares representation is known as [Fermat's factorization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method), which has generalizations such as the [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve). One can also use various cyclotomic factorizations such as [Aurifeuillian factorizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345950/242) (see the mongraph below for more on such).

John Brillhart, D. H. Lehmer, J. L. Selfridge, Bryant Tuckerman, and S. S. Wagstaff Jr.,
*Factorizations of $\,b^n\pm 1,\,$* 2nd ed., Contemporary Mathematics, vol. 22, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1988.