# Stuck at a length 80 for a Prime-Generating Polynomial.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Looking at Eulers prime generating polynomial

$\large n^2-n+41$

it generates these primes $n\in$ $[0,40]$

```
  41, 41, 43, 47, 53, 61,..., 1447, 1523, 1601
```

I started to look for my own polynomial of the form

$an^2-bn+c$

and noticed that Eulers primes can be labeled with sequential odd numbers

```
  1   3   5   7   9  ...  75    77    79

  41, 43, 47, 53, 61,..., 1447, 1523, 1601
```

Setting the last pair $b=79$ and $c=1601$ yields this formula

$n^2-79n+1601$

and found it produced $80$ non-distinct primes for $n\in [0,79]$
which is the longest prime chain I could find.

**Questions**

Why does the last Euler number $1601$ paired with an odd number $79$ yield

$\large n^2-79n+1601$

Do other polynomials follow a similar pattern to create prime chains greater than $80$?

Comment: $ 1^2 - 4 \cdot 41 = -163. $   Your version $79^2 - 4 \cdot 1601 = -163. $ You have simply taken a shift of the original, and your primes are the same as those given by $n^2 - n + 41$ with  something like $-39 < n < 39,$ considerable duplication...

Comment: Your polynomial is simply $\,f(39-x),\,$ for $\,f(x) = x^2+x+41,\,$ i.e. [as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/142234/242) in the dupe, it's a shift (and reflection) of the common Euler polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ in the linked dupe. See the Theorem there for generalizations.